# Make geocoding map zoom on scroll

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-geocoding-api

I am looking at two different geocode examples I found and I am looking to get the best of both features. I have not had much experience with geocoding and I find the google docs hard to follow

This one does everything I want except scroll in when the user uses the mouse wheel. http://jsfiddle.net/Ep7Rr/

I would like this one if I could get the marker to move as the user drags the map like in the first one.http://jsfiddle.net/AjeTc/

I know there are different ways such as `new GMap2` and `new google.maps.Geocoder`

The first one works with this code

```
<script>
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()){
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    var center = new GLatLng(54.18173, -6.35284);
    map.setCenter(center, 15);
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});  
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(5);

    GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(){
      var point = marker.getPoint();
      map.panTo(point);
      document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
      document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);
    }); /*END GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(){*/

    GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
      map.clearOverlays();
      var center = map.getCenter();
      var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
      map.addOverlay(marker);
      document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(5);
      document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(5);

      GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
        var point =marker.getPoint();
        map.panTo(point);
        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);
      }); /*END GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {*/
    }); /*END GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {*/
  } /*END if (GBrowserIsCompatible()){*/
} /*END function load*/
```

And the second uses this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAddress() {
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
  var address = document.getElementById('fullAddress').value;


  return false;
} /*END function showAddress*/ 

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.18173, -6.35284);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Please post code, not just links.

Comment: The first block of code is using API v2, which has been deprecated since 2010 and will stop working from November 19 this year. The second block of code is using API v3.

Comment: I seen that it will be deprecated and will stop later this year. Im trying to get the functionallity of the first one where the marker will move as the user drags the map and take it into the second one where the map will zoom in and out using the mouse wheel

Comment: So, what have YOU done so far? Can we see that so that we can help you further?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the event when the map is dragged.
Update the position of the marker by getting the map center
Geocode the position of the marker

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
  updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
  marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
  geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
});
```

like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ZYV9N/